# ubuntu packaging help

Tags: games, packaging, c++, debian

HI I have been using Ubuntu for a while now and would like to create Apps for Ubuntu. I have made a fun game and would like to have it in the software centre but I do not know how to create a debian package for it. Any help is greatly appreciated. My game is made using c++ and SFML

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this Link : http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/

It will help you to give a head start around Ubuntu packaging.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your game is Ubuntu specific, I'd submit my new package to Debian first. you can get a lot of help from Debian mentors mailing list.

To subscribe please go to [this](https://lists.debian.org/debian-mentors/) page.

Packages in Debian unstable are automatically synced in Ubuntu before [DebianImportFreeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebianImportFreeze).

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq

Comment: Good one , I am giving Ubuntu ,so he can choose.:)